# Using of overloaded new/delete and STL in shared library

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, operator-overloading, std

I've faced with problem which was caused by conjunction of overloaded operators ***new/delete*** and ***STL*** (especially std::string). Here's my case...

I compile shared library (call it libfoo.so), in which I overload operators ***new*** and ***delete***. In order to not impact program which will use this library, I made symbols ***new*** and ***delete*** hidden.
Also my library uses STL, especially std::string, which as I expect should use my operators ***new/delete*** since it is template class.

When I compile library with -O1 and above I get SIGABRT which was cause by using different operators **new/delete** in basic_string constructor/destructor. ***new*** is called from libstdc++.so but ***delete*** is called from my library.

When I compile library with -O0 or -fno-inline operators ***new/delete*** for basic_string constructor/destructor are both called from libstdc++.

I made minimal example which show such behavior: https://github.com/yekatkov/CustomNewDelete
Steps for reproducing of error are in Readme.md.

Is it normal behavior of optimization? Or may be I should use std::string in different way? How to force stl classes in my library to use my ***new/delete***? Suppose my real library has tons of stl classes, hence I can't redefine allocator for each of them. :(

I use glibc 2.27, gcc 5.5.0

Be glad to listen any ideas :)

Thanks!

Comment: There's different overloads to `new` and `delete`. Can't really know what the implementations of `std::string` do under the hood. I would really not go with this approach if I were you, instead I would implement a custom allocator and use it on the containers.

Comment: Even though [this refers to Windows DLL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846511/new-and-delete-operator-overloading-for-dll), this may explain the issue you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are attempting to have multiple different global `operator new`s, one in your dylib, and another for anyone else that uses your dylib.

There can be only one. That's why it's called a *global* operator.

If you have more than one, you can get the behavior that you're seeing. (Or something else, you're walking into UB-land here)

(later)
Both libstdc++ and libc++ externally instantiate `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` (aka `std::string`) in the dylib. This means that when you call non-inlined methods in `string`, you're running code out of the dylib, which will NOT use your hidden operator new/delete to allocate/free memory.

Comment: The best solving of my problem is not to overload global new / delete. Unfortunately, I haven't such option. :(